# Use Electron to select specific folder with program in it, and install files into directory

Tags: node.js, electron

So I'm currently looking for a method to open a specific folder, containing let's say FiveM.exe

When the folder is selected it should download and install some files to it.

Is this even possible with Electron?

And how would you go around and do so, I know how to do a select folder and file dialog, but the rest I'm not too sure about.